# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'

Tags: undefined

Build at: 2021-09-13T04:00:55.316Z - Hash: d597e9c75de38cc870b6 - Time: 2764ms

Error: src/app/servers/edit-server/edit-server.component.ts:18:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.

18     this.server = this.serversService.getServer(1);
~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/servers/server/server.component.ts:16:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.

16     this.server = this.serversService.getServer(1);
~~~~~~~~~~~

√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-09-13T04:00:56.000Z - Hash: d597e9c75de38cc870b6 - Time: 393ms

Error: src/app/servers/edit-server/edit-server.component.ts:18:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.

18     this.server = this.serversService.getServer(1);
~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/servers/server/server.component.ts:16:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }'.

16     this.server = this.serversService.getServer(1);

Answer (score 0):

Adding ! to ‘this.serversService.getServer(1)!;’ should fix it because the ‘!’ operator indicates this value isn’t nullable.